# How can I update my employee's bank account

Tags: python, class

I want my class to be able to update my employees. How should I do it?

```
class emmploye:
   account=0
   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name=name
      self.salary=salary
   def update(self):
      self.account=account+salary
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems did you face? Try to be more specific about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Took the liberty of editing typos, and using camel case for class name, we have

```
class Employee:
  account = 0
  def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
  def update(self):
    self.account += self.salary
```

Create new object:

```
employee1 = Employee()
```

Update object:

```
employee1.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, a few edits should be done:

```
class employee:
   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name=name
      self.salary=salary
      self.account = 0
   def update(self):
      self.account += salary
```

Then create your `Employee` object and call the `update` method:

```
employee = Employee()
print employee.account #prints 0
employee.update()
print employee.account #prints salary
employee.update()
print employee.account #prints 2 times salary
```

and so on.

Now `account` is an attribute for the class and the increment is updated correctly each time you call the `update` method.

**More explaination**

You declared

```
account = 0
```

then you set

```
self.account = account + salary
```

Notice that this way you will always be overwriting `self.account`, since it's not the same variable `account`.

So, your code always does something like this:

```
self.account = 0 + salary
```

which is just

```
self.account = salary
```

over and over.

The solution I've proposed uses the same (attribute) variable and hopefully does what you need!